# Adding a network printer with lpadmin but using gnome keyring for auth

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, cups, printer

I am using lpadmin to add a printer to the system, Ubuntu 18.04 for this example. The problem is that the file is stored in plaintext in /etc/cups/printers.conf. Is there a way for it to use gnome keyring instead?

The command I use at the moment is:

```
lpadmin -p printername -v smb://username:password@host/printer -m lsb/usr/filedriver.ppd -E
```

So after this the password is written to /etc/cups/printers.conf, which I know is also only readable by root. I've been trying to see how to pass the auth part to gnome keyring but found nothing so far.

Comment: Never found a solution for the password in cleartext too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the belief is that, if anyone would be able to read the pritners.conf and steal it, your system is already compromised.

<strike>I have not found any solution to this problem. For now, make sure you do not use any sensitive passwords as the password for the printer...</strike>

This is not much of a problem, since it's only possible to read it as root.

Reference links:
https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/3174

> CUPS.org User: mike
>
> [For future reference, we do not consider this to be a security
>   issue...]
>
> Hardcoding usernames and passwords has never been recommended, but we
>   restrict the permissions on the printers.conf file and sanitize the
>   device-uri that is returned by Get-Printer-Attributes and passed in
>   argv[0] to the backends to minimize exposure for users that chose to
>   go this route.
>
> The recommended solution is to use forwarded credentials, either via
>   Kerberos or regular username/password information passed with the
>   print request. IIRC, the Red Hat print status monitor supports this
>   mechanism and uses the GNOME keyring to remember the necessary
>   authentication information as needed.
>
> Storing system-wide password information in a user keyring will never
>   happen.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109433/samba-printer-usernames-and-passwords-security-problem

> I really don't feel this is a problem and I will explain you why. If
>   anybody got root access they could just sniff the traffic so every
>   time anybody tries to authenticate the attacker can grab the hash of
>   the password.
>
> If anyone gets root access they can start arp spoffing DNS spoofing
>   spoofing spoofing, which makes your network if compromised even more
>   compromised.
>
> If anyone gets root access they can log the keystrokes /events
>   /everything going on
>
> *nix users tend to have the most updated version of common sense
>
> Somebody with system on an windows system got the same amount of
>   access.
>
> Worrying about someone reading a clear text password for an account
>   with lover privileges, when they got root, is like worrying about a
>   crack in the floor when the building is crumbling around you
>
> What you should worry about is people getting root ;)
>
> Stay safe